# Alert dialog doesn't show anything

Tags: java, android

I have an Alert Dialog and when I press the button to show what I chose, it shows nothing, only the black faded screen like something has to show.

There is my code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder raspunsgresit = new AlertDialog.Builder(Intrebarea644.this);
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(Intrebarea644.this);
final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.raspuns644, null);
raspunsgresit.setView(view);
if(view.getParent()!=null)
   ((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
raspunsgresit.setPositiveButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just the `AlertDialog.Builder`. You need to `create()` the `AlertDialog` then `show()` it. 
So, your code will look like :

```
final AlertDialog.Builder raspunsgresit = new AlertDialog.Builder(Intrebarea644.this);
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(Intrebarea644.this);
final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.raspuns644, null);
raspunsgresit.setView(view);
if(view.getParent()!=null)
 ((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
raspunsgresit.setPositiveButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin){
 }
});
raspunsgresit.create().show();
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work... the app crash when i'm trying to open the alertdialog again.

Comment: What's on the LogCat. Add it with your question and notify me.

Comment: As you've removed it from it's parent there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Yeap but there is a problem actually... what if i put here the whole code?